# statement.getGeneratedKeys() and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I've learned it the hard way that last_insert_id in mysql is not pool-safe. i.e. if you are pooling connections, you'll get messed up insert_ids. 
How does java's statement.getGeneratedKeys() get the key on inserts? Is it pool-safe?

Answer (score 3):

I am quoting the relevant text from the MySQL Connector/J [internals](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/autoincrement-with-connectorj.html) here:

> You should be aware, that at times, it
>   can be tricky to use the 'SELECT
>   LAST_INSERT_ID()' query, as that
>   function's value is scoped to a
>   connection. So, if some other query
>   happens on the same connection, the
>   value will be overwritten. On the
>   other hand, the 'getGeneratedKeys()'
>   method is scoped by the Statement
>   instance, so it can be used even if
>   other queries happen on the same
>   connection, but not on the same
>   Statement instance.